# Query multiple tables and columns in Rails and Postgresql with a single search parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm constructing an API using Rails with a Postgresql database. I have a **User** model and the users table has 3 columns, **email**, **name** and **city**.

I would like to create a single URL that allows users to search multiple fields in my **User** model, so for example, when the user searches in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/search?term=foo
```

it searches for the term 'foo' in the **email**, **name** and **city** columns and return all the matches. This is similar to when you search on the iTunes Store (http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=foo).

So far this is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
  email
  name
  city
FROM
  users
WHERE
  email = '#{term}' OR
  name = '#{term}' OR
  city '#{term}';
```

This works but is way too slow (>4000ms) when you have a lot of records. Does anyone know a better SQL or a Rails/ActiveRecord method that can make this query better? I already added indexes to all three columns.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to use that code for production purposes, then it's [recommended](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) to use ? marks in the query string, in order to avoid SQL Injection. Like in the following sample:

```
User.where("email = ? OR name = ? OR city = ?",  params[:term],  params[:term], params[:term])
```

You asked how things could be made speedier, well database indexes might work in this case; so you need to create [migration file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) that could be called AddIndexes

```
class AddIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_index :users, :email
     add_index :users, :name
     add_index :users, :city
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion on avoiding SQL injection. As for the adding index part, I've already added indexes to the 3 columns, but it's still slow (>4000ms) for some queries. I have about 3 million records in this table, I guess that may just be too big.

Comment: @HarryWang How about using batches? I just had a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html (a new concept for me too!) and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches
You might find this Rails cast useful too http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3
So when using batches you could limit the amount of Users used in the SQL condition with id’s or with batch_size. Perhaps this could speed up things.

Comment: @HarryWang about the SQL, you could also ask from Database Administrators' stack exchange (http://dba.stackexchange.com/), about how to make the SQL quicker too

Comment: Thanks for noting batches. This is very helpful! Thanks a lot!!